# Geth v1.9.25 stuck with transactions on txpool (private network - clique)

Tags: go-ethereum

We have a private network (Clique) with nodes running Geth version 1.9.2. There are 3 validation nodes on the network and at least other 3 non-mining nodes.

A few days earlier we tried to update to version 1.9.25. When we update the validation nodes, Geth starts getting stuck with transactions in the transaction pool.

To make Geth process more transaction, we had to restart it ... until it got stuck again, over and over again... What we've seen that makes it get stuck less often is to decrease the number of transactions in the pool, from 2.000 to 400, but it still freezes sometimes.

So the final solution was downgrading back to version 1.9.2 but only the validators... other nodes are still running version 1.9.25 with no problem.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? (we also tried versions 1.9.24 and 1.9.20, but had the same problem).